# Can't view data properly in PyCharm variable explorer

Tags: pycharm

When I'm trying to access any variable from the "View as..." option, part of the data is cut-off. I'm trying to vertically align the data in the center of the cell.

PyCharm version: 2018.1.4 (Community Edition)
UI plugin: [Material Theme UI](https://github.com/ChrisRM/material-theme-jetbrains)

[Data is not vertically aligned in cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Ci1q.png)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I figured it out.

In `Settings | Appearance | Material Theme` go to the Panels tab and select the "Compact Table Cells" option.